# Factorization of $16 \times 512$ matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have a lot of matrices whose size is 16 x 512 (let´s called them $A_{k}$) and a matrix $B$ of size 16 x 512. I would like to write the matrices $A_{k}$ like $A_{k}=C_{k}*B$ where $C_{k}$ has size 16 x 16. I don't know how to get the matrices $C_{k}$ or if it is always possible for any matrix $B$.

If it is not possible for any matrix $B$, how can I choose a matrix $B$ so this factorization is posible?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the matrices $A_k$ and on $B$, this can very well be impossible; for example it is impossible if $B=0$ and $A_j\neq 0$ for some $j$.

More generally, this will be possible if and only if all the rows of the matrices $A_k$ are in the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{512}$ spanned by the $16$ rows of $B$; thus if the subspace $W$ spanned by the rows of the $A_k$'s has dimension bigger than $16$, it won't be possible, no matter the matrix $B$. If it has dimension $16$ or lower, you can just take $16$ rows in your $A_k$'s that span $W$ and define $B$ as the matrix formed by these rows.

Comment: If all the matrices $A_{k}$ have dimension 16x512... the subspace that is spanned by their coloumns will never have a dimension greater than 16 right?

Comment: @RodrigoSernaPérez True, but here I'm talking about their rows. This is important because my $W$ is the space generated by all the rows of *all* the matrices $A_k$, thus it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{512}$ generated by $16k$ vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Given fat matrices $\mathrm A, \mathrm B \in \mathbb R^{16 \times 512}$, we have the following linear matrix equation in $\mathrm X \in \mathbb R^{16 \times 16}$

$$\mathrm X \mathrm A = \mathrm B$$

We have $16 \cdot 512$ equations in $16^2$ unknowns. Thus, we have a severely *overdetermined* system with $32$ times more equations than unknowns. Hence, let us look for a *least-squares* solution

$$\hat{\mathrm X} := \arg\min \| \mathrm X \mathrm A - \mathrm B \|_{\text{F}}^2$$

Minimizing $\| \mathrm X \mathrm A - \mathrm B \|_{\text{F}}^2$, we obtain the *normal equations*

$$\mathrm X \mathrm A \mathrm A^{\top} = \mathrm B \mathrm A^{\top}$$

If $\mathrm A$ has *full row rank*, then $\mathrm A \mathrm A^{\top}$ is invertible and, thus, the *unique* least-squares solution is

$$\boxed{\hat{\mathrm X} = \mathrm B \mathrm A^{\top} \left( \mathrm A \mathrm A^{\top} \right)^{-1}}$$

Plugging this least-squares solution into the original linear matrix equation, we obtain

$$\hat{\mathrm X} \mathrm A = \mathrm B \, \underbrace{\mathrm A^{\top} \left( \mathrm A \mathrm A^{\top} \right)^{-1} \mathrm A}_{=: \mathrm P_{\mathrm A^{\top}}} = \mathrm B \mathrm P_{\mathrm A^{\top}}$$

where $\mathrm P_{\mathrm A^{\top}}$ is the projection matrix that projects onto the *column space* of $\mathrm A^{\top}$, i.e., onto the *row space* of $\mathrm A$. The least-squares solution is a solution to the original matrix equation if and only if

$$\mathrm B \mathrm P_{\mathrm A^{\top}} = \mathrm B$$

or, alternatively, if and only if

$$\mathrm P_{\mathrm A^{\top}} \mathrm B^{\top} = \mathrm B^{\top}$$

We conclude that the least-squares solution is a solution to the original matrix equation if and only if the columns of $\mathrm B^{\top}$, i.e, the **rows** of $\mathrm B$, are in the **row space** of $\mathrm A$. If that is the case, then the $16$ entries of the $k$-th row of $\hat{\mathrm X}$ tell us how to weight the $16$ rows of $\mathrm A$ in order to build the $k$-th row of $\mathrm B$.

Answer (score 0):

You have a hard problem of linear algebra. What you want to have is the solution of the matrix equation
$$\begin{bmatrix} a_{ij} \end{bmatrix}_{1\le i\le16\\1\le j\le 512}=\begin{bmatrix} x_{ij} \end{bmatrix}_{1\le i\le16\\1\le j\le 16}
*\begin{bmatrix} b_{ij} \end{bmatrix}_{1\le i\le16\\1\le j\le 512}=\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma\space x_{ik}b_{kj} \end{bmatrix}_{1\le i\le16\\1\le j\le 512}$$ For this you need to verify the compatibility of the $16\cdot512$ equations in $216$ (=$16^2$) unknowns $x_{ij}$
$$a_{ij}=\Sigma_{1\le k\le 16} (x_{ik}b_{kj})$$
Except, perhaps, some particularity of your matrices that allow easy calculations, this is the general way of solving your problem.